# A sentence full of grammar problems

Tags: tense, commas, participles, run-on-sentences

I wrote a sentence under the online news comment section:

> I would say he does a good job this time, practically showing he's tough with zero consequence, ideally showing what's normal and should be done.

But I am confused with many things,

1. he **did** what I think is a good job before the news is out, so I should use past tense "did", but I was commenting under the latest news section(but still two days old), it's so recent that I feel **does** is more proper, and to me since I know he did a good job only when I read the news, it's like he just **does** it a few second ago, so it's more natural to me to use present tense, so what should I use?
2. In the second half of the sentence, it sounds well to use adverb practically and ideally, but there is no verb there, is this usage valid? Or I have to use comma to separate the sentence? Like "*...this time, practically, showing...*", but this sounds strange to me.

Comment: 1. *did* because in context this statement could only be made after the "job" was completed (when there is only one instance). But you could say "I would say he *does* a good job *most of the time*" where the time frame is unspecified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are commenting on a news article that relates what a person did, you should  say

> He did a good job

If you want to say that someone habitually does quality work, you would say

> He does a good job

The fact that you read about it only recently is not relevant.

I'm a little confused by the second part of your question. First there **is** a verb there: *practically* and *ideally* modify the verb *showing*. Second, *practically* has two meanings:  *almost* and *in a practical manner*. Used in the first way:

> He practically ran all the way home.

Used in the second way:

> Practically, it's too far to walk

If you mean to use it in the second way, which I think you do, it would be clearer if it came after *showing*.
As in

> ...showing practically that he is tough....

Comment: "its too far to walk" - it's